# HasOptional does not return the object of relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to create an application using Asp.Net MVC and Entity Framework. In this application I have one User that has one Package and to make the relationship between them I used the `HasOptional` but when I try to find the User the Package does not return joined with User.

Why is it happens and how do I fix this?

**User**

```
public class User
{

    public long id { get; set; }
    public Package package {get;set;}
```

**Package**

```
public class Package
{
        public int id  { get; set; }
        public String name {get;set;}
```

**Map**

```
public class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>{
    public UserMap(){
        this.ToTable("Users");
        this.HasKey<long>(u => u.id);

        this.HasOptional<Package>(u => u.package);
    }
}
```

**Using**

```
//it should to return the Package too but still doesn't
User user = context.users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.id == userSession.id);

Debug.writeLine("Package is null: " + user.package == null); //it is returning true
```

Comment: Please, format your code properly

Comment: Is it Entity Framework 6.x?

Answer (score 0):

One-to-one in EF6.x is configured the following way:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasOptional(p => p.package)
        .WithRequired();
}
```

Comment: Tried as you suggest but it is changing to whenever I add a new Package it needs to vinculate the new Package to a User and that´s what I ain´t wanted. I would to add a new User and new Package and only after that vinculate them as "User->has->Package"